# Is there a Grunt.js Plugin To help Detect Open HTML elements?

Tags: gruntjs

I love grunt and sometimes when working in a ton of code it's easier to leave a tag open. Is there a grunt script that will parse the HTML on build and then message you to the console where a broken element is or a non-closed element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there's [HTMLHint which has this grunt wrapper](https://github.com/yaniswang/grunt-htmlhint). It's a linter for HTML which will check for unclosed elements, uppercase tags, unique ids and more (see the [wiki page](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/Rules)).

Note that you have to specify the options in the grunt plugin because it has no defaults. Here's an example configuration that I've used before in the past:

```
htmlhint: {
    build: {
        options: {
            'tag-pair': true, // Force tags to have a closing pair
            'tagname-lowercase': true, // Force tags to be lowercase
            'attr-lowercase': true, // Force attribute names to be lowercase e.g. <div ID="header"> is invalid
            'attr-value-double-quotes': true, // Force attributes to have double quotes rather than single
            'doctype-first': true, // Force the DOCTYPE declaration to come first in the document
            'spec-char-escape': true, // Force special characters to be escaped
            'id-unique': true, // Prevent using the same ID multiple times in a document
            'head-script-disabled': true, // Prevent script tags being loaded in the <head> for performance reasons
            'style-disabled': true // Prevent style tags. CSS should be loaded through <link>
        },
        src: ['static/**/*.html']
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Fantastic - I also discovered html-validation-grunt will do this as well - Thanks! https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html-validation - And sure enough it caught my open div.